# How to loop an array in seed_fu fixture instead of manually entering each element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

I have an array of 150(ish) time zones.

```
x = ["Central Time (US & Canada)", "Pacific Time Zone (US & Canada), .....]
```

I have a seed_fu fixture file:

```
TimeZone.seed(:name,
    { name: "Central Time (US & Canada)" },
    { name: "Pacific Time Zone (US & Canada)" }
 )
```

Is there way that seed_fu will allow to loop through my array instead of manually creating an seed file entry for each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try something like this:

```
TimeZone.seed(:name, *x.map { |zone_name| { name: zone_name } })
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked amazingly well.  Mind if I ask why the splat operator is needed?

Comment: the *seed* method doesn't expect an array, it wants just an open-ended list of values, so not `seed(:name, [a, b, c, d])`, but just `seed(:name, a, b, c, d)`, thus the splat is needed.